# Change BackColor Of Button

Tags: api, winapi

Engineer 
I Have Created 3 Buttons With BS_OWNERDRAW Style 
Now How Can Brush

Function WndProc(Hwnd,message,wparam,lparam)
CASE WM_CTLCOLORBTN If wparam=Button1 Then 
WndProc=hBrushbtn1Elseif Wparam=Button2 Then  WndProc=hBrushbt 2 End if Have To Get Hwnd Of Lparam Of Wparam And How ?

I m not able to get Brush handle To Each  button

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: `WM_CTLCOLORBTN` is sent to the button's **parent** window, not to the button's window. Is your `WndProc` assigned to the parent window or to the button?

Comment: To Hwnd Of Window .. First Create Window Then Ref To WndProc And Message WM_CREATE Create Button Also The Text With TextOutA Cannot Be Center Align When GetClientRect Wparam,rc , Could Not Load A Sample Photo Of It Here

Comment: Please Give Me A Sample Code To Hook Msgbox Dialog Box Then Use Message  WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC To Change The BackGround Color

Comment: But I am Testing In VBA Not C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle [WM_DRAWITEM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-drawitem) message in parent window when an owner-drawn button want to change its color.

Create the owner-drawn button with [BS_OWNERDRAW style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/button-styles):

```
   hwndButton1 = CreateWindowW(L"BUTTON", NULL,      
       WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_OWNERDRAW,
       10, 10, 100, 100, 
       hWnd, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
```

In the Window procedure of the parent window of the button:

```
case WM_DRAWITEM:
{
    LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDIS = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
    if (hwndButton1 == lpDIS->hwndItem)
    {
        SetDCBrushColor(lpDIS->hDC, RGB(255, 0, 0));

        SelectObject(lpDIS->hDC, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));

        RoundRect(lpDIS->hDC, lpDIS->rcItem.left, lpDIS->rcItem.top,
            lpDIS->rcItem.right, lpDIS->rcItem.bottom, 5, 5);

        return TRUE;
    }
}
    break;
```

Comment: Unfortunately In Vb or vba  We Cannot Write LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDIS = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam  , i Think Use CopyMemory Or Like This